# TypeError: undefined is not an object(evaluating 'navigation.state')-React Native

Tags: react-native

I m getting TypeError: undefined is not an object(evaluating 'navigation.state')in React Native.

```
const DashboardFooter = ({navigation}) => {
      const activePage = navigation.state.index;
      return (
           <TouchableOpacity
            style={styles.tabIconContainer}
            onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Dashboard')}>
            <Image
              source={
                activePage === 0
                  ? require('../assets/images/dashboard/menu.png')
                  : require('../assets/images/dashboard/menu-active.png')
              }
              style={{width: 24, height: 24}}
             />
            <Text style={styles.titleMenu}>Menu</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        );
    };
```

I m getting this error[image]!

Comment: The answer is here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/55221448/9346400

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cross posting from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55221232/undefined-is-not-an-object-evaluating-navigation-navigate/55221448?noredirect=1#comment109311817_55221448):

It seems like you're not properly creating the component so that the `navigation` property is set. You'll need to make sure to wrap the component using the [`withNavigation`](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/3.x/with-navigation/) higher order component.

```
export default withNavigation(MyComponent);
```